# Change Current Frame acc. to Active Layer

Tags: python, scripting

I need to write a script, that automatically changes the current frame according to the active layer. For example if layer 1 is active, current frame is 1. If layer 2 is active current frame is 11. There are 2 problems:

If I run this code:

```
 bpy.ops.anim.change_frame(frame=25)
```

it gives error:

```
Expected an timeline/animation area to be active
```

I can read the active layer via `bpy.context.scene.active_layer` however, I have no idea how to make this script always check the active layer.

Comment: Answer provided. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if it solved your problem to help future users

Comment: Use `context.scene.frame_set(frame)` to set  the current frame to `frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The draw callback hack.**

There are a number of ways to make a script run constantly, via [scene update handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html), modal operators, and draw callbacks to name a few.

The scene update handlers run a squi-billion-times a second which IMO is overkill. A modal timer, akin to one in ***`text editor > templates > python > Modal Timer Operator`*** would do the trick, but has some downside as it potentially blocks auto-save, and other functionality while running.

The draw callback, primarily designed for `bgl` and `blf` displays can be used.

Example, left in the `blf` which writes on 3d view. The frame is set using the active layer.

```
import bpy
import blf
#from gi.repository import Gdk
class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self, context, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                   self.draw_text_callback,(context,),
                   'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

    def draw_text_callback(self, context):
        font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.
        # draw some text
        blf.position(font_id, 15, 50, 20)
        blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)
        blf.draw(font_id, "%s %s" % (context.scene.name, self.prop))
        scene = context.scene
        layer = scene.active_layer
        frame = (layer + 1) * 10 + 1
        if scene.frame_current - frame:
            scene.frame_set(frame)

    def remove_handle(self):
         bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test call            
    dc = DrawingClass(bpy.context, "Auto Layer Running......")
```

Hint: If you give the script a `.py` extension in text editor you can import it into other scripts / console etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the below script:

```
import bpy

if bpy.context.scene.active_layer == 1:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current=1
elif bpy.context.scene.active_layer == 2:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current=11
```

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't check active layer continuously. If I run this script on layer 2 then it changes current frame, however if I go back to previous layer it doesn't change current frame, unless I run this script again.