# How can I catch a workspace change event?

Tags: python, workspaces

I want to write a function, which will be called after changing the workspace.

I thought, that i can find workspace change event in `bpy.app.handlers`, but it looks like where is no such handler here… What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19668/execute-a-python-function-whenever-the-user-interacts-with-the-program where depsgraph update is akin to old scene update.

Comment: @batFINGER unfortunately, changing workspace doesn't cause depsgraph update event...

Comment: Correct, the idea is it runs frequently enough to flag it.   Similarly for A property with a getter  fired on a UI draw or a modal timer.  The property getter would be ideal way to fire when saved value has changed. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property

Comment: Out of interest... What do you have in mind here?, are you going to keep a history of visited workspaces?  Could go whole hog on this question and  fudge an on context change event comparing current, since context changes accordingly without which member being flagged, the context is what it is.,  against a repr  value copy of all (or selected props to watch)...

Comment: Of course, I can make a timer to check this every 0.1sec, but I think there is more performance method

Comment: Just remembed this too https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110689/15543

Comment: @batFINGER it's a bit easily in 2.80 https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135970/context-is-incorrect-when-calling-from-a-timer/135995#135995 Be interested to see how you go, quite likely in the timer thread `context.workspace is None` .. and overriding the context will be no use in this case.  If not and it is like the window manager it will work.

Comment: Still [intrigued](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135968/how-can-i-catch-a-workspace-change-event?noredirect=1#comment233825_135968)  _Vote to close as unclear **why** you are asking_ Lol..

Comment: @batFINGER i want to transfer some area's properties from one workspace to others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set/Reset Statusbar on a Different Workspace](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251232/set-reset-statusbar-on-a-different-workspace)

Comment: @MartyFouts my question is more general, and it was asked earlier, and accepted answer in that question seems to be incorrect for me (because you can do, see the answer below).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `msgbus` and subscribe to the `workspace` property of the window class: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window.workspace

[image]

```
import bpy

handle = object()

# Triggers when window's workspace is changed
subscribe_to = bpy.types.Window, "workspace"

def notify_test(context):
    print(context.workspace.name)
    context.workspace.status_text_set("Hello: {}".format(context.workspace.name))

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(bpy.context,),
    notify=notify_test,
)

bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
```

Output:

```
Layout
Scripting
Texture Paint
...
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

[How to get an event when an object is selected?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150809/how-to-get-an-event-when-an-object-is-selected)

[Msgbus - How to subscribe to bpy.context.scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204906/msgbus-how-to-subscribe-to-bpy-context-scene)

Comment: After all these years, finally get the solution! Many thanks, I'll give you some more points, just need to wait 24 hours, because of site rules

Comment: Is it possible to have this automatically run at startup? This error occurs if trying to load it it at module registration time: AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'workspace'

Comment: Using msgbus only seems to work when the user explicitly clicks a workspace name with the mouse. It does not work when using the keyboard shortcuts (It is called "Cycle Workspace" aka "screen.workspace_cycle" operation. Can the solution be extended to cover this?