# Want to run two scripts when I change to edit mode

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

Im not good at python script, but I want to run two actitons when I change to edit mode. or I want to know register any Hoykey for run this scripts?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
```

This is to switch to Face Selection mode at the same time as you change to the edit mode (as in Maya). I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you really need a script for this? <kbd>TAB</kbd> let's you switch between object and edit mode and once in edit mode <kbd>3</kbd> switches to face select. Did I misunderstand you and this is meant to be used in an add-on instead of your general workflow when switching to edit mode?

Comment: @rjg yeah, I used to work with my laptop so I need this script indeed....

Comment: Doesn't matter whether you're using a laptop or workstation. Once you press TAB and set the selection to *Faces*, the setting is stored as long you change it. Don't get your point... Can you elaborate please why do you think this is nice to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for (and maybe there is a way to do this without scripting).

This add-on will let you activate edit mode (with face select) by pressing ctrl + shift + Q in 3d viewport (see comment in code to change hotkey).

I have modified the Operator Simple template (Text Editor, Templates->Python):

```
import bpy


bl_info = {
    "name": "Set Edit Mode",
    "description": "Set edit mode with face selection",
    "category": "Object",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
}

def main(context):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        o = context.active_object
        return o is not None  and o.type == 'MESH' and \
            context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH'

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

keymap = None

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    c = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if(c):
        m = c.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')   
        # Hotkey - ctrl + shift + Q
        i = m.keymap_items.new("object.simple_operator", 'Q', 'PRESS', \
            shift = True, ctrl = True)
        keymap = (m, i)

def unregister():
    if(keymap != None):
        keymap[0].keymap_items.remove(keymap[1])

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bpy.msgbus` to identify when mode is changing:

`handle/owner` is a way to identify what has been added by you.

`subscribe_to` is a rna path to what you want to be informed about.

Though, subscribing to `bpy.context.mode` does not work, it seems.

```
import bpy

handle = object() 

def notify_test(*args):
    print( "Mode:", bpy.context.mode )

subscribe_to = bpy.types.Object, "mode"

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(1, 2, 3),
    notify=notify_test,
    )
```

From [brockmann answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150809/how-to-get-an-event-when-an-object-is-selected/150881#150881).

And [initial example here](https://developer.blender.org/P563).

Answer (score 1):

*Adding to the existing answers:*

In the upcoming Blender 2.81 there is a new operator that let's you do this, which means you can have a single function call or a shortcut to switch to edit mode and enabled face select.

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set_with_submode(mode='EDIT', mesh_select_mode={"FACE"})
```

The shortcut can be included in your keymap by setting the identifier to `object.mode_set_with_submode`. Set the mode to *Edit Mode* and enabled *Face* select. The tricky part is to decide what the shortcut should be.

[image: Keymap]