# How to obtain/enable Blender 2.8 "shortcut properties"?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I'm trying to add a custom shortcut that enables selecting vertex/edge/face mode inside mesh edit mode. I'm trying to do this inside a custom keymap preset.

The image shows two instances of the same shortcut:
The upper part of the image is the custom keymap preset.
The lower part of the image is from the preset known as 'industry standard'.

Industry standard preset has the additional option that allows you to select vertex mode (encircled) while the same 'sub-option' is missing inside the custom preset (question mark) despite using the same operator.

How do I enable these 'sub-options'?
Why is the name of the shortcut the same as the operator and is there a way to change it?

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/151141

Answer (score 0):

In 2.81 `ic_keymap` removed, and this function you can use now from `object.mode_set_with_submode`.

If you open 2.81 with industry compatible keymap, you will see, that now it use`object.mode_set_with_submode` for this shortcut