# Wireframe Automatic Activation

Tags: wireframe

Is there a way to automatically activate the Wireframe whenever I switch from Object to Edit mode? That would make the workflow faster and less confusing.
Thank you

Comment: but if you click in once and change back...it is in that mode. So only do it once when start working!? or do you open a new file, make a few clicks and open the next file?

Comment: No, but it's just a single key press (SHIFT-Z) to toggle between the two.

Comment: What should happen when you switch back from Edit to Object mode? The switching of the shading type to wireframe can be done by scripting. But you probably want to save the previous shading type for Object mode? Feel free to edit your question to give more context and have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151138/want-to-run-two-scripts-when-i-change-to-edit-mode and here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221696/store-viewport-display-color-and-toggle-shading-type