# How to make snapping similar to measure tool?

Tags: python, snapping

I am making an addon where I need a snapping function similar to the measure tool. And it would be awesome if you can extend that function to snap to the grid.

[image]

I know how to draw on viewport with the `GPU` module but lack knowledge about snapping to vertex, edges, faces, or grid.

Please help me in building that function.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193202/19156

Comment: @lemon your answer works only if you select an object but I want to snap without selecting any object and the snapping should work for the world grid also. Similar to measure tool snapping.

Comment: You can raycast over the scene (scene.ray_cast) in order to pick the object under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on the operator modal draw example (template).

Perspective:

[image]

Ortho:

[image]

The script is in two parts.

First try to hit an object in the scene and if no success try to hit the 3d view grid.

- Hitting an object in the scene:

Based on `scene.ray_cast`, which gives hit object, location and face index.

Though, we won't hit if the mouse cursor is near but outside of the objet. As workaround, a possibility is to try to hit along a circle which is around the mouse cursor position (and keep the closest result).

- Hitting the grid:

The grid is visible as X/Y plane except if we are on side view.
We can use `intersect_line_plane` from `mathutils.geometry` to get the intersection of the view direction with this plane.
The grid scale is given by the `region3D.view_distance`.
If we take `log10(region3D.view_distance) - 1`, the grid scale is `10 ** this value` (the equivalent to mm, cm, 10cm, m, 10m, etc. indication on the 3d view).

In both cases we end with a polygon. Either an object face or a square on the grid plane.

We just have to snap on it if a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed.

Snapping is in two parts. Snap to vertices and snap to edges.

- Snap to vertices:

We get each vertex of the polygon, project it back to the view and compare its distance to the mouse cursor. If less than a radius value, we snap.

- Snap to edges:

We have to get the position on the edge that appears to be the closest to the mouse position, when it is projected on the view.
For simplicity (avoiding geometry calculation that are too complex for me), I did it iteratively, with a dichotomy (loop until the result is acceptable under an epsilon value).

Full code.

```
import bpy
import blf
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_line_plane
from math import pi, cos, sin, floor, ceil, log10
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils
from gpu_extras.presets import draw_circle_2d
 
RADIUS = 20
STEPS = 12

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    if self is None: print("self is None")
    color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
    if self.hit_grid: color = (0, 0, 1, 1)

    if self.hit_object or self.hit_grid:
        region = context.region
        region3D = context.space_data.region_3d
        circle_loc = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region3D, self.hit_location)
        if circle_loc is not None:
            gpu.state.line_width_set(4.0)
            draw_circle_2d(circle_loc, color, RADIUS)
           
#ray_cast adding the view point in the result
def ray_cast(context, depsgraph, position):
    region = context.region
    region3D = context.space_data.region_3d

    #The view point of the user
    view_point = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, region3D, position)
    #The direction indicated by the mouse position from the current view
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, region3D, position)

    return *context.scene.ray_cast(depsgraph, view_point, view_vector), view_point

#try to find the best hit point on the scene
def best_hit(context, depsgraph, mouse_pos):
    
    #at first we raycast from the mouse position as it is
    result, location, normal, index, object, matrix, view_point = \
        ray_cast(context, depsgraph, mouse_pos)

    if result:
        return result, location, index, object, view_point

    #but if we are near but outside the object surface, we need to inspect around the 
    #mouse position and keep the closest location
    best_result = False
    best_location = best_index = best_object = None
    best_distance = 0

    angle = 0
    delta_angle = 2 * pi / STEPS
    for i in range(STEPS):
        pos = mouse_pos + RADIUS * Vector((cos(angle), sin(angle)))
        result, location, normal, index, object, matrix, view_point = \
            ray_cast(context, depsgraph, pos)
        if result and (best_object is None or (view_point - location).length < best_distance):
            best_ditance = (view_point - location).length
            best_result = True
            best_location = location
            best_index = index
            best_object = object
        angle += delta_angle

    return best_result, best_location, best_index, best_object, view_point

def search_edge_pos(region, region3D, mouse, v1, v2, epsilon = 0.0001):
    #dichotomic search for the nearest point along an edge, compare to the mouse position
    #not optimized, but easy to write... ;)
    while (v1 - v2).length > epsilon:
        v12D = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region3D, v1)
        v22D = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region3D, v2)
        if v12D is None: return v2
        if v22D is None: return v1
        if (v12D - mouse).length < (v22D - mouse).length:
            v2 = (v1 + v2) / 2
        else:
            v1 = (v1 + v2) / 2
    return v1

def snap_to_geometry(self, context, vertices):
    region = context.region
    region3D = context.space_data.region_3d

    #first snap to vertices
    #loop over vertices and keep the one which is closer once projected on screen
    snap_location = None
    best_distance = 0
    for co in vertices:
        co2D = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region3D, co)
        if co2D is not None:
            distance = (co2D - self.mouse_pos).length
            if distance < RADIUS and (snap_location is None or distance < best_distance):
                snap_location = co
                best_distance = distance
                
    if snap_location is not None:
        self.hit_location = snap_location
        return
    
    #then, if no vertex is found, try to snap to edges
    for co1, co2 in zip(vertices[1:]+vertices[:1], vertices):
        v = search_edge_pos(region, region3D, self.mouse_pos, co1, co2)
        v2D = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region3D, v)
        if v2D is not None:
            distance = (v2D - self.mouse_pos).length
            if distance < RADIUS and (snap_location is None or distance < best_distance):
                snap_location = v
                best_distance = distance

    if snap_location is not None:
        self.hit_location = snap_location
        return

def snap_to_object(self, context, depsgraph):

    #the object need to be evaluated (if modifiers, for instance)
    evaluated = self.hit_object.evaluated_get(depsgraph)

    data = evaluated.data
    polygon = data.polygons[self.hit_face_index]
    matrix = evaluated.matrix_world
    
    #get evaluated vertices of the wanted polygon, in world coordinates
    vertices = [matrix @ data.vertices[i].co for i in polygon.vertices]
    
    snap_to_geometry(self, context, vertices)    

def floor_fit(v, scale):
    return floor(v / scale) * scale

def ceil_fit(v, scale):
    return ceil(v / scale) * scale

def snap_to_grid(self, context, crtl_is_pressed):
    region = context.region
    region3D = context.space_data.region_3d

    view_point = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, region3D, self.mouse_pos)
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, region3D, self.mouse_pos)

    if region3D.is_orthographic_side_view:
        #ortho side view special case
        norm = view_vector
    else:
        #other views
        norm = Vector((0,0,1))

    #At which scale the grid is
    # (log10 is 1 for meters => 10 ** (1 - 1) = 1
    # (log10 is 0 for 10 centimeters => 10 ** (0 - 1) = 0.1
    scale = 10 ** (round(log10(region3D.view_distance)) - 1)
    #... to be improved with grid scale, subdivisions, etc.

    #here no ray cast, but intersection between the view line and the grid plane        
    max_float =1.0e+38
    co = intersect_line_plane(view_point, view_point + max_float * view_vector, (0,0,0), norm)

    if co is not None:
        self.hit_grid = True
        if crtl_is_pressed:
            #depending on the view angle, create the list of vertices for a plane around the hit point
            #which size is adapted to the view scale (view distance)
            if abs(norm.x) > 0:
                vertices = [Vector((0, floor_fit(co.y, scale), floor_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((0, floor_fit(co.y, scale), ceil_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((0, ceil_fit(co.y, scale), ceil_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((0, ceil_fit(co.y, scale), floor_fit(co.z, scale)))]
            elif abs(norm.y) > 0:
                vertices = [Vector((floor_fit(co.x, scale), 0, floor_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((floor_fit(co.x, scale), 0, ceil_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((ceil_fit(co.x, scale), 0, ceil_fit(co.z, scale))), Vector((ceil_fit(co.x, scale), 0, floor_fit(co.z, scale)))]
            else:
                vertices = [Vector((floor_fit(co.x, scale), floor_fit(co.y, scale), 0)), Vector((floor_fit(co.x, scale), ceil_fit(co.y, scale), 0)), Vector((ceil_fit(co.x, scale), ceil_fit(co.y, scale), 0)), Vector((ceil_fit(co.x, scale), floor_fit(co.y, scale), 0))]
            #and snap on this plane
            snap_to_geometry(self, context, vertices)

        #if no snap or out of snapping, keep the co                
        if self.hit_location is None:
            self.hit_location = Vector(co)

def main(self, crtl_is_pressed, context):
    self.hit_location = None
    self.hit_grid = False
    
    depsgraph = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

    result, location, index, object, view_point = \
        best_hit(context, depsgraph, self.mouse_pos)

    self.hit_location = location
    self.hit_face_index = index
    self.hit_object = object
    self.view_point = view_point
    
    if result and crtl_is_pressed:
        snap_to_object(self, context, depsgraph)
    elif not result:
        snap_to_grid(self, context, crtl_is_pressed)
        
class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_draw_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE' or event.type in {"LEFT_CTRL", "RIGHT_CTRL"}:
            self.mouse_pos = Vector((event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y))
            main(self, event.ctrl, context)
            
        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            self.mouse_pos = Vector()
            self.hit_object = None
            
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalDrawOperator.bl_idname, text="Modal Draw Operator")


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Modal Draw Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To run the script, search for `Simple Modal View3D Operator` (and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap).

[image]

Comment: Getting this error when I move the mouse away from the grid ```Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 210, in modal
  File "\Text", line 198, in main
  File "\Text", line 175, in snap_to_grid
  File "\Text", line 97, in snap_to_geometry
AttributeError: Vector subtraction: (NoneType - Vector) invalid type for this operation
```

Comment: @Karan, corrected I think. Give it a try.

Comment: Can you add snap support for `object origin`, `edge center`, and `face center`?

Comment: if I've time... but can't you give it a try?

Comment: I can't understand this complex code :(

Comment: I can explain more. Ask questions. This should be more constructive than just doing it for you.

Comment: There is one more bug, when I move the mouse away from the grid the ⭕ get removed I think it should be in mouse pos if there is not `self.hit_grid`

Comment: Yes, I've added several tests for the results of `location_3d_to_region_2d`which can return None if no 2d location was found.

Comment: Got this error while in edit mode `Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 210, in modal
  File "\Text", line 196, in main
  File "\Text", line 125, in snap_to_object
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 4 out of range, size 0
`

Comment: Yea, Karan, please, enhance the code... if it need object mode, check that when the operator start. Thanks.

Comment: We participate here to give guidance, not to do all the job...

Comment: Can you explain why the error occurs?