# Is it possible to create a function that is performed on the render engine change?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I would need to perform a function on the render engine change, for example:

```
def function_on_engine_change(self,context):

   if context.engine =='CYCLES':
       print('Cycles')
   else:
       print('Is not Cycles')
```

The call of this function should obviously take place automatically if the engine is changed

I was looking on the blender handles but found nothing, I wonder if there is any trick that does this

Comment: `msgbus` might be an option: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150881/31447

Comment: @brockmann lol, even used same link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `msgbus`**

There is a relatively new and mostly undocumented feature of blender that fires a callback when a property is changed.  Check if your version has this feature in python console.

```
>>> bpy.msgbus
<module 'msgbus'>
```

Related

https://developer.blender.org/P563

[Origins to the down of the object by default](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161823/origins-to-the-down-of-the-object-by-default/163258?r=SearchResults&s=3|8.4555#163258)

[How to get an event when an object is selected?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150809/how-to-get-an-event-when-an-object-is-selected/150881?r=SearchResults&s=2|9.2456#150881)

For this case (IMO) can substitute `context.scene.render.engine` for `context.engine`

```
>>> C.engine
'BLENDER_EEVEE'

>>> C.scene.render.engine
'BLENDER_EEVEE'

>>> C.scene.render
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render

>>> type(C.scene.render)
<class 'bpy.types.RenderSettings'>
```

[image]

Use msgbus to invoke a callback whenever the "`engine`" property of `bpy.types.RenderSettings` is altered.

```
import bpy


handle = object()

subscribe_to = bpy.types.RenderSettings, "engine" 


def notify_test(context):
    print("Notify changed!", context.scene.render.engine)

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(bpy.context,),
    notify=notify_test,
)

bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
```

Note using `bpy.types.Context`, "engine"  does not work.

**For versions without `msgbus`**

Can use a `depsgraph_update_post` (or prior `scene_update_post`) handler.

```
import bpy

engine = bpy.context.scene.render.engine

def engine_change(scene):
    global engine
    if scene.render.engine != engine:
        engine = scene.render.engine
        print("changed", engine)


if hasattr(bpy.app.handlers, "scene_update_post"):
    handler = bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post
else:
    handler = bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post

handler.append(engine_change)
```

Comment: It sounds great, I was also thinking of a function called by bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post, here it would check a variable if the engine really changed, what do you think of this?
Too much cpu work? blender 2.79 not support bpy.msgbus

Comment: Yes that would work too.  I would use `msgbus`

Comment: Edited answer to include. Getting hard to keep track of changes.  Do you have `depsgraph_update_post` in 2.79, if not use `scene_update_post`   (it fires at a huge rate)