# How can I update panel properties only once on event

Tags: scripting, properties, panel

I am writing an addon that deals with creating objects and assigning them properties based on panel parameters. I want the panel to update it's parameters to match the properties of my selected object only when I first select it. If I update for every draw, I will not be able to change those parameters because it will automatically snap back to the parameters of my selected object. How can I update the panel properties only once when I select a new object?[image]

Comment: Not sure this will solve your problem but maybe explore getter/setter : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245167/86891

Comment: Also maybe it would be nice to include the code for defining these properties, and consider storing them on `bpy.types.Object` instead of `bpy.types.Scene` (if it's the case) that way you won't risk overriding your parameters

Comment: @Gorgious https://github.com/rocstar293/TyTools.git Here is my Git repo. I made a branch with better commentary so you can get an idea of what's going on. The relevent files are panel.py, operators.py, presets.py, and utils.curve.py. but that's a lot so you might be able to see the gist from the utils.curve, which is where I set the object props from scene.props. If you can let me know if I'm going about this the right way, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!