# Print object name every time I change active object (click)

Tags: python

Tried this code, but it seems have some issue, can't figure it out (need your help):

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    #print("Active object:", scene.objects.active.name)
    print("Active object:", bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.name)

#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(my_handler)
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(my_handler)
```

the old original code is commented.

Comment: can u please elaborate the issues? syntax error? isn't called? if yes, when isn't it called...?

Comment: oh sorry, I restarted blender and used it again and it seems to work as expected. So I'll leave the question so others can do the same.

Comment: Note this won't fire only every time the object is changed, it will fire every time *anything* is changed.

Comment: Gorgious, you are right. How to handle here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150809/how-to-get-an-event-when-an-object-is-selected