# Removing space draw callbacks after losing the handle?

Tags: python, scripting, gpu-module

A small edit of test code from [GPU Shader Module (gpu) "Mesh with Random Vertex Colors"](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#mesh-with-random-vertex-colors) to save the handle to the driver namespace ...

```
import bpy
import gpu
import numpy as np
from random import random
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
mesh.calc_loop_triangles()

vertices = np.empty((len(mesh.vertices), 3), 'f')
indices = np.empty((len(mesh.loop_triangles), 3), 'i')

mesh.vertices.foreach_get(
    "co", np.reshape(vertices, len(mesh.vertices) * 3))
mesh.loop_triangles.foreach_get(
    "vertices", np.reshape(indices, len(mesh.loop_triangles) * 3))

vertex_colors = [(random(), random(), random(), 1) for _ in range(len(mesh.vertices))]

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_SMOOTH_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader, 'TRIS',
    {"pos": vertices, "color": vertex_colors},
    indices=indices,
)


def draw():
    batch.draw(shader)


h = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

bpy.app.driver_namespace["foo"] = h
```

Such that we can remove via the python console

```
>>> dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
>>> h = dns['foo']
>>> h
<capsule object "RNA_HANDLE" at 0x7f4841cdbf90>

>>> bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(h, 'WINDOW')
```

... otherwise it is drawn on the screen until blender is shut.

Or is it?  Is there a way, via python API,  to remove all or any draw callbacks without the handle?

> Related re making a class to "handle the handles"
>
> [I can't get a SpaceView3D draw callback to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161769/i-cant-get-a-spaceview3d-draw-callback-to-work)
>
> [How do you remove a draw handler after it's been added?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75612/how-do-you-remove-a-draw-handler-after-its-been-added)
>
> [handle vertex property changes with msgbus.subscribe_rna](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160909/handle-vertex-property-changes-with-msgbus-subscribe-rna)

Comment: I don't know too much what this question was about, but was it necessary to create the 'gpu-module' tag? Are there many other questions that would benefit from this tag?

Comment: There is a new `gpu` python module in 2.8,  replacing the `bgl` module to draw on the viewport.  Feel  the gpu tag refers more to the hardware.  `bmesh` as a standalone module has a tag, yet again `blf` doesn't.

Comment: Ah ok. Seems appropriate then.

Comment: Suggest [adding](https://blender.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1119) a definition for the 'gpu-module' tag. Already seen the first misuse of it as a generic gpu tag.