# Instancing a space theme with a draw callback

Tags: python, interface

[image]

In a somewhat tongue in cheek answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197340/15543 have come across the possibility of having one instance of a 3d view showing a different theme than another.

Updating  a space theme color within a draw callback, and again,  is setting the colour for an instance.   Any  `bgl` required is being done for us. (*Not the right one, shows the concept.  Code was cobbled together for a question revolving around a scene property (same scene per screen)*)

Feel this could be useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161773/15543 in finding a combination of region and event type.

**The question.**

How can I harness this to show another theme (or one colour of as above will suffice)  based on a space property correctly. per instance.

*My particular use case is being able to "theme" a particular script in the text editor*