# How to set a different background color for each node editor

Tags: interface

I often work with two Shader Editors side by side to work on Object and World nodes. Is there any way to change these background colors to get it more distinguishable? Other suggestions are welcome too.
[image: UI blender]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bit janky but you could use a *Frame* node, set it to a custom color, uncheck *Shrink* in its properties then stretch is as far as you can with a node.

[image]

Comment: If you could answer [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197349/instancing-a-space-theme-with-a-draw-callback) it would answer this one lol.

Comment: @batFINGER Haha ! I would love more customisation per editor like the local collections in the 3D Viewport... Without resorting to janky workarounds or adding draw callbacks here and there :) But to be fair it might be overkill with the workspace workflow or the ability to use separate windows with different workspaces

Answer (score 7):

**Kinda like this.**

[image]

In hoping for an answer to [Instancing a space theme with a draw callback](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197349/instancing-a-space-theme-with-a-draw-callback) will add an edit to it here

If you set one node editor to world, it changes the color of the other, and labels the world one (correctly). The idea is to both label and color the same one, but... *hence the question*.

```
import blf
import bpy


highlight_color = (0.8, 0, 0.5)

class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        from bpy import context
        self.prop = prop
        self.col = context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.space.back[:] 
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.draw_handler_add(
            self.draw_text_callback, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

    def draw_text_callback(self):
        from bpy import context
        font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.
        if not hasattr(context, "scene"):
            return None
        space = context.space_data
        if space.shader_type == 'WORLD':
            context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.space.back = highlight_color
            # draw some text
            blf.position(font_id, 18, 50, 0)
            blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
            blf.draw(font_id, f"{self.prop}")

        else:
            context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.space.back = self.col

    def remove_handle(self):
        from bpy import context
        context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.space.back = self.col
        bpy.types.SpaceNodeEditor.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')


dc = None


def register():
    global dc
    dc = DrawingClass("World")

def unregister():
    global dc
    if dc:
        dc.remove_handle()
        dc = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I stand corrected :) Nice application of UI personalization !!