# Draw in a region not found in space type

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'd like to create a footer where there's no "FOOTER" bl_region_type
for example in the 3D view,
it seems impossible to do in python?
is this hardcoded in C++?

```
import bpy

class HELLO_PT_world(bpy.types.Header):
    bl_idname      = "HELLO_PT_world"
    bl_label       = "HelloWorld"
    bl_space_type  = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "FOOTER"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="Is This Working?")
        
        
print("Trying to register")
from bpy.utils import register_class
register_class(HELLO_PT_world) #-> RuntimeError: Error: Region not found in space type
                               #   Well I want to add a new region in this space... Duh...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easily checked.**

The type of region available to each of the area types is probably in the docs somewhere, however it is easily checked using the python console.

With a 3d view area as the variable `area` (`C.screens.areas[3]` in this example)

```
>>> area
bpy.data.screens['Scripting.001']...Area

>>> area.type
'VIEW_3D'

>>> for region in area.regions:
...     region.type
...     
'TOOL_HEADER'
'HEADER'
'TOOLS'
'UI'
'WINDOW'
```

if it's not there, it's not possible with python.

Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161773/15543

Comment: Ah that is sad, 
i was hoping it was not hard coded per area type

Comment: Do  panels  even register / draw in header / footer / window  regions when they are available?  The poor ol' python console only has two.

Comment: ah, correct we need to use bpy.types.Header (even for footer)